# MCP error - looking for minecraft main jar... not found

Tags: minecraft

I'm trying to do my own Minecraft mod for a few months, but I'm in big trouble…
I want to install MCP for the mc Version 1.8.8, I already had 2 errors which I
could fix myself, but the 3rd error is impossible to find a solution for on the Internet.

So I already had the ScalaC not found error and the twitch error, but now I have the error: "Looking for minecraft main jar… not found".

I've found somebody on a Forum which had the same error, but nobody had a working solution.

It would be very nice if somebody could explain to me how to fix this.

Comment: Why are you using MCP directly and not using Forge (or Bukkit)?

Comment: I want to create a aimple CLIENT modification without forge, so ist easy to install and not so laggy :)

Comment: Forge clients can connect to vanilla servers just fine.

Comment: Ive found the error, I were programming in the wrong Java IDE! Now im programming in the Right one but ive a new error...

Comment: After Ive opened mcp with eclipse ive got an **warning** Icon at my source Folder. Does anybody knows hot to fix this?

Comment: I have still got the error message "Looking for minecraft main jar… NOT FOUND"!

Comment: You need to import the minecraft_1.8.8.jar file into the library.

Answer (score 1):

Its okay. I too had the problem but found out that MCP just makes the Main jar file when its not there, read the codes. It should say :"Copying minecraft main jar... OK"